# Display modal popup without page loading using asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to display modal popup without page loading actually i used jquery to display modal but i am getting error code is.

```
<obout:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="duplicate">
  <Template>
    <asp:Button ID="lnkbtnDuplicate" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtnDuplicate_Click" AlternateText="Duplicate" CssClass='<%#Container.DataItem["schedule1"]%>'></asp:Button>
  </Template>
</obout:GridTemplate>
```

and jquery is

```
$(function() {
  $('#<%=lnkbtnDuplicate.ClientID%>').click(function() {
    $("#popupdiv").dialog({
      title: "jQuery Popup from Server Side",
      width: 430,
      height: 250,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Close: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
})
```

Error is :

> The name 'lnkBtnViewDetails'does not exist in the current context .

Comment: The code you've posted here is not what the error is complaining about. The error is complaining about 'lnkBtnViewDetails' not 'lnkbtnDuplicate'. please post the code relating to 'lnkBtnViewDetails'

Answer (score 0):

That's because the **B** is in lower case in the Id of the button `lnkbtnDuplicate` and jQuery is case sensitive.

Comment: sry for that i made a mistake........... i have changed B to b but getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using  'lnkBtnViewDetails'?
i dont see it..
You are getting error about  'lnkBtnViewDetails'